# Feedback on my Subscript code

Tags: function-construction, code-review

I have written a code, and I need a little feed back..

I want to make the `Subscript` distributive across (1) addition and (2) multiplication to mimic short-hand for added vectors.  For example, in $(p+2k)_i=p_i+2k_i$ the LHS is short-hand for RHS, where the index is not allowed to be on the coefficient 2.  Finally, I need exception, where the numeric quantity 0 should be allowed to take an index:  that is, $0_i$ should not go to $0$.

My code is:

```
Clear[Subscript];

Subscript[Plus[a_, b___], idx_] := 
  Subscript[a, idx] + Subscript[b, idx];

Subscript[Times[a_, b___], idx_] := 
  Times[Subscript[a, idx], Subscript[b, idx]];

Subscript[a_?NumberQ, idx_] /; a != 0 := a;
```

What I did was to define `Subscript` as functions, which is already built-in Symbol in Mathematica.  The code seems to really work, but I don't know if I deserve a pat-on-the-back for being clever, or be reprimanded for overwriting a built-in Symbol (or for any other bad coding behavior).

Also, is there any obvious way anyone can see this piece of code going wrong?  Thanks!!

Comment: I would use `ClearAll[Subscript]` in case `Attributes` has previously been set to something undesirable. Otherwise, there's nothing wrong with defining a function like `Subscript`, because it has no built-in meaning. However, I don't know what the real intent is, so it's hard to write anything other than a comment. E.g., what about dot products, or `Subscript[a + b c,i]`? That result doesn't look like something you normally want.

Comment: @Jens Ah!  Very good point about dot products.  I suppose that this is restricted to sums of vectors, and products of numbers and vectors.  But not square of vectors.  Thank you for feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In my opinion `Subscript` is a formatting function and should not be occupied with this kind of definition.  With such a definition in place you will have to rely on `SubscriptBox` any time you want a simple subscript without these rules.
- Your definitions as written insert a raw sequence into `Subscript` that I do not believe you want.  I shall assume that $(a+b+c)_7$ should be expanded to $a_7+b_7+c_7$ and not $a_7+b_{c,7}$

To correct these I would define:

```
ss[a_ + b___, idx_] := ss[a, idx] + ss[+b, idx];

ss[a_ * b___, idx_] := ss[a, idx] * ss[1 b, idx];

ss[a_?NumberQ, idx_] /; a != 0 := a;

Format[x : ss[args__]] := Interpretation[Subscript[args], x]
```

Now:

```
ss[q + r + s + x y z, 7]
```

> $q_7+r_7+s_7+x_7 y_7 z_7$

```
% // InputForm
```

> ```
> ss[q, 7] + ss[r, 7] + ss[s, 7] + ss[x, 7]*ss[y, 7]*ss[z, 7]
> ```

---

Jens comments that attaching a definition to `Subscript` in the way you did is perfectly acceptable.  If you choose that option then you will probably want to define a new subscript function for the purposes of pure formatting.  For example:

```
MakeBoxes[realSubscript[a_, b__], fmt_] := 
  SubscriptBox[a, RowBox @ Riffle[{b}, ","]]

realSubscript[1, 2]
```

Comment: The [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html) doesn't agree  with you. An operator without built-in meaning can be a very convenient way to define a new function that automatically comes with a notational form. The latter doesn't mean that it's *only* a formatting construct.

Comment: @Jens That's fine.  I don't always agree with the documentation or the popular opinion.  I would (and do) use *other* operators directly.  However I use subscript in labels, etc. often enough that I would not want to have to define a *new* subscript function though I suppose that's an option for others.

Comment: Sure - you marked the statement as an opinion - I just wanted to mention the alternative opinion.